# JQuery -> Ajax -> PHP -> 500 internal server error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am struggling with a 500 internal server error. I have made just a basic script to test, but its just getting 500 anyways. Do you see a typo or logic errors? I am to blind right now to see an error.

**AJAX**

```
$("#select_kjede").change(function(){
         var kjede = $("#select_kjede option:selected").val();

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "bestilling/controller.php",
          data: { 
            kjede: kjede 
          }
          })
          .done(function( msg ) {
               alert(msg);
          });
});
```

**PHP**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $message = $_POST["kjede"];
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log("."OLOL ".$message."</script>";
}
```

In the PHP-script i have tried a numerous methods, included `if(isset($_POST['kjede'])`

**EDIT:**
In Chrome console under the error -

```
send 
b.extend.ajax 
(anonymous function) 
b.event.dispatch 
v.handle
```

**How can i console out the server errors?**

Comment: I am positive that "kjede" contains a id-number

Comment: Have you checked errors? In error log or with error_reporting? `console.log` btw needs a closing bracket.

Comment: Have error_reporting, but non errors are reported. Have closed console.log, but nothing happend @u_mulder

Comment: It's usually a very bad idea to send script tags in ajax responses. Instead, send a new state using json, and use javascript to update the state on the client. Or just send html, without script tags.

Comment: @Arjan I have tried to just send a plain string for testing, but its 500 anyways

Comment: The problem is not in the four lines of php that you posted. But I guess that the file contains more code and the issue might be there somewhere. You really should make sure that error reporting is enabled and check the error log (of the webserver).

Comment: post your full php code

Comment: To see the response from the server (assuming you have error display turned on in your server) you can go to the `Network` tab in chrome developer tools and click on the failed request (it will be indicated by a red color). Then go to the `Preview` or `Response` tab. To see only ajax requests use the `XHR` filter on the top bar.

Comment: Respons:
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Date: Sat, 20 Sep 2014 12:09:13 GMT

Server: Apache/2.2.16

Vary: Accept-Encoding

Content-Encoding: gzip

Content-Length: 343

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: This means that your server has debug mode off. add the following lines at the beginning of the file: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` and check the response again

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to ask what your form looks like. But I could not comment. Your code works fine with the following form.

```
<form id="select_kjede">
    <select>
        <option>option_one</option>
        <option>option_two</option>
        <option>option_three</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="save"/> 
</form>
```